# Decode promiscuous Wi-Fi Packets offline

Tags: ieee-802.11

I am using an embedded Wi-Fi module (ESP8266) to act as a logger to find devices that are using my LAN network. I can get this module to sniff Wi-Fi packets promiscuously, but now I need to decode the raw packets so that I know the IP and MAC address from devices in my network.

I want to make sure that these packets do contain IP and MAC addresses.

I also attached the hex dump log here:

[image: promiscuous sniff 1]
[image]

My question is: is there any method to decode these hex values to get the MAC and IP addresses of devices in the network? I tried to use Wireshark -> Import Hex Dump -> use encapsulation type ranging from Ethernet, 802.11 Wireless LAN, 802.11 Wireless LAN with radio information but it returns empty.

Comment: You tried to use Wireshark and?

Comment: I rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, your Wi-Fi frame payload will be encrypted, and we cannot/will not help you decode the encryption. The MAC addresses will be in the unencrypted frame headers. The first six octets of the frame headers should be the destination address, and the next six octets should be the source MAC address.

There is software that will help you see this better, but recommendations are off-topic here. Wireshark needs its data in a specific format (PCAP).